# How do I pull individual words from a list when needed?

Tags: python, words, mixed

```
#Word Jumble Game

import random
import string

def jumbled():
words = ['Jumble', 'Star']#, 'Candy', 'Wings', 'Power', 'String', 'Shopping', 'Blonde', 'Steak', 'Speakers', 'Case', 'Stubborn', 'Cat', 'Marker', 'Elevator', 'Taxi', 'Eight', 'Tomato', 'Penguin', 'Custard']
count = 0    
loop = True
loop2 = True
while loop:
    word = string.lower(random.choice(words)
    jumble = list(word)
    random.shuffle(jumble)
    scrambled = "".join(jumble) 
    while loop2:
        print '\n',scrambled,'\n'
        guess = raw_input('Guess the word: ')
        quit = set(['quit','Quit'])
        choice = 'quit'
        if guess.lower() == word:    
            print '\nCorrect!'
            count+=1
            print "You took",count,"trie(s) in order to get the right answer",jumbled()
        else:
            print '\nTry again!\n'
            count+=1
            if count == 3:
                if words[0]*2:
                    print "It looks like you're having trouble!"
                    print 'Your hint is: %s'(words) # I'm trying to pull a word from the above list here.



jumbled()
```

So here I am, playing a game I've programmed that chooses a random word from the list, mixes it up then I have to correctly guess it. This process works and if I get it wrong, I will get a message saying to try again and if correct, will congratulate me then onto the next word!

A problem I'm having is that I want to be able to give a hint if the user incorrectly guesses after 3 times. However, if the program gives me, say 'jumble' as a word that I have to guess and I guess it wrong 3 times, I would like a hint based off that word. I can't get the word star then a hint that has to do with jumble, can I?

With the code I have now (I have commented what line I'm having trouble with), I get an error saying that the string is not callable, I don't know what to call...

Please help!

If it's not too much trouble, I also need to be able to type in quit then the game would quit itself, unfortunately, I don't know how to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the unjumbled word in `word` so you could for example use

```
print 'Your hint is: %s'%word
```

Very easy hint though

You could make a `dict` to map words to clues eg

```
hint_dict = {'Jumble': 'Name of this game.", "Star": ...}
```

and then use

```
print 'Your hint is: %s'%hint_dict[word]
```

Comment: Gosh darn! How stupid of me, haha. Forgot to use % after every %s/d I use. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

I can break down what you"ll have to do based on what you've given me.

"So here I am, playing a game I've programmed that...:"

(-) chooses a random word from the list.

Well, try a dictionary like the following, rather than a list:

```
wordHints = {"word1":("hint1_1", "hint1_2", "hint1_3", ..., "hint1_n"), 
             "word2":("hint2_1", "hint2_2", "hint2_3", ..., "hint2_n"),
                                       ...                            ,
             "wordm":("hintm_1", "hintm_2", "hintm_3", ..., "hintm_n")}
```

When you want to fetch wordi's j'th hint, you simply use:

```
hinti_j = wordHints[wordi][j - 1]
```

So, if you want a random hint, you use your list (yay)! 
*n.b.*"import random" used:

```
wordList = []
for word in wordHints:
   wordList.append(word)

randomCPU = newList[random.randint(0, len(newList) - 1)]
```

Moving on...

"..., mixes it up then I have to correctly guess it. This process works and if I get it wrong, I will get a message saying to try again and if correct, will congratulate me then onto the next word!

A problem I'm having is that I want to be able to give a hint if the user incorrectly guesses after 3 times. However, if the program gives me, say 'jumble' as a word that I have to guess and I guess it wrong 3 times, I would like a hint based off that word. I can't get the word star then a hint that has to do with jumble, can I?"

Well I've given you most of the building blocks so far, so I think the larger portion of that is best if you try on your own, but here is a hint and an answer to your question:

Yes, you can get the word "star", then a hint that has to do with "jumble"!
Whether or not you have the word "star" is trivial, as you know how to fetch it and fetching hints from a dictionary in this manner does not obliterate your hints. 
What's important to know is how to fetch your hint that has to do with jumble.

*i.e.*: you want "jumble"'s k'th hint

```
wordHints["jumble"][k - 1]
```

*e.g.*: you want "jumble"'s 5th hint, defined as "boogie"

```
print(wordHints["jumble"](5 - 1))
>>> boogie
```

Hope that helped; cheers!